# Why is VBScript's bitwise And failing in one case?

Tags: vbscript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm using VBScript to parse a return code inside some Windows installer stuff. I wanted to confirm that I was doing the bitwise stuff correctly, so I jotted down some `Echo` statements, and found that one of them didn't produce the result I expected:

```
WScript.Echo (&H01010101)                ' prints 16843009 (0x01010101). Correct!
WScript.Echo (&H01010101 And &Hff000000) ' prints 16777216 (0x01000000). Correct!
WScript.Echo (&H01010101 And &H00ff0000) ' prints 65536    (0x00010000). Correct!
WScript.Echo (&H01010101 And &H0000ff00) ' prints 16843008 (0x01010100). What's happening here?
WScript.Echo (&H01010101 And &H000000ff) ' prints 1        (0x00000001). Correct!
```

That fourth one appears to have only masked the bottom two bytes. Okay, sure, I guess I can see where maybe it gets converted to the smallest int that can hold it before it gets `And`ed and so the mask is shorter than what's being masked or something like that, but then why does the final case work?

If I throw in something in the highest byte it works:

```
WScript.Echo (&H01010101 And &Hf000ff00) ' prints 256      (0x01010100).
```

and here are some other cases:

```
WScript.Echo (&H01010101 And &H0000f0ff) ' prints 16842753 (0x01010001).
WScript.Echo (&H01010101 And &Hf00000ff) ' prints 1        (0x00000001).
```

which sort of support the idea that it's getting stored in a WORD, not a DWORD, but I still don't really understand what's happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&h0000ff00` is not interpreted as a Long, but as an Integer, which in VBScript is a [16-bit (short) signed integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

> `Integer`: Contains integer in the range -32,768 to 32,767.

Signed integers are encoded using [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), meaning that bit sequences starting with a `1` are interpreted as negative numbers. Thus the value `&hff00` becomes -256.

Your other examples don't trigger this behavior, because they're either larger than 16 bit, so they're automatically treated as Long, or are smaller than `&h8000` (32768, or binary `1000 0000 0000 0000`), so they're positive signed integers.

To avoid this pitfall tell the interpreter to treat the number as a Long by appending another ampersand:

```
WScript.Echo (&h01010101 And &h0000ff00&)
```

or use the decimal value:

```
WScript.Echo (&h01010101 And 65280)
```

You could also define the hex number as a string and convert it to a Long using the `CLng` function:

```
WScript.Echo (&h01010101 And CLng("&h0000ff00"))
```

Just using `CLng` on the hex number won't work, though. If you tried something like this:

```
CLng(&h0000ff00)
```

the number would already be a (negative) signed short integer when the function gets to see it.

Comment: Great explanation.